# PocoDynamo (the provided key element does not match the schema)

Tags: servicestack, pocodynamo

I have created a table in Dynamo Db, with Id as the primary key and customerID as sortkey.

When i query an item by Id as shown below, I get error "the provided key element does not match the schema"

```
var db = new PocoDynamo(awsDb);
```

db.GetItem("aa4f0371-6144-4bd9-8980-5066501e37aa");

When I remove the sortkey from the dynamo DB, it works as expected.

What is the correct way to get an item by Id, which also has a sort key associated with it.

```
public class Notification
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [RangeKey] //Sort Key
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid LinkId { get; set; }
    public string PreviewText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [PocoDynamo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) you can [specify both Hash Key and Range Key](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#specifying-a-hash-key) with a `[CompositeKey]` attribute, e.g:

```
[CompositeKey(nameof(Id), nameof(CustomerId))]
public class Notification
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid LinkId { get; set; }
    public string PreviewText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great. I did try the composite key approach as specified in the documentation but didn't work.

I tried your suggested approach again and it didn't work as expected.

I can only get it to work with the following syntax.

var test = db.GetItem<Notification>(new DynamoId(Id, CustomerId));